# Go to a page in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, routes

I want to write a function in a component.ts file which, when executed, routes to a new page. How can I do that?

I have searched online for answers but they only tell you how to route from an html file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the angular router into the component.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  myMethod(): void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/path');
  }
}
```

Read about the Angular router and various routing methods [here](https://angular.io/guide/router)